# Zooming photo using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm trying to zoom photo using jquery and it's working too. [demo](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/92126558/uddhab.me.pn/index.html).
But the problem is that I'm unable to get back on previous size.
Here is the code -

```
jQuery("#myimg").click(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith( "<img id='myimgBig' src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0f510b2337a6077896036f31d4f45eb7?s=420' width='420' height='420' title='that&#39;s me' alt='Uddhab' />" );
});
jQuery("#myimgBig").click(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith( "<img id='myimg' src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0f510b2337a6077896036f31d4f45eb7?s=120' width='120' height='120' title='that&#39;s me' alt='Uddhab' />" );
});
```

I want to go back to #myimg on clik on #myimgBig. But the above code not working :(
Where is the wrong!! Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) functionality for that. The second image is created dynamically, so the handler isn't attached.

```
$("body").on("click", "#myimg", function() {
    $(this).replaceWith("<img id='myimgBig' src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0f510b2337a6077896036f31d4f45eb7?s=420' width='420' height='420' title='that&#39;s me' alt='Uddhab' />");
});

$("body").on("click", "#myimgBig", function() {
    $(this).replaceWith("<img id='myimg' src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0f510b2337a6077896036f31d4f45eb7?s=120' width='120' height='120' title='that&#39;s me' alt='Uddhab' />");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6b84B/).

Answer (score 2):

Your click event on #myimgBig is being registered before the element is actually in your document (you only inject this element into the document onclick of the original image. As a result, there is no link between your click function for #myimgBig and the actual image element.

Off the top of my head I would either load both elements initially (and in doing so, make sure both click event handlers are registered on the correct elements) or  add an explicit onclick attribute on your second image; or better still, wrap the image element in a span or similar element and use that to handle the clicking, en just inject the image inside the span.

Loading both elements initially you would get something like

```
...your html page here...
<img id="myimg" src="..." /><img id="myimgBig" src="..." />
```

And your jQuery could be

```
$("#myimg").click(function() {
  $(this).toggle();
  $("#myimgBig").toggle();
}
$("#myimgBig").click(function() {
  $(this).toggle();
  $("#myimg").toggle();
}

$("#myimgBig").toggle();
```

This should hide your big image initially after the page load, and on click toggle between the two.

Comment: I understood the benefit of using toggle.

Answer (score 0):

use css effects

```
.image{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:80px;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    border:1px solid black;
    /* Apply a CSS3 Transition to width, height, top and left properties */
    transition: width 0.3s ease,height 0.3s ease,left 0.3s ease,top 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease,height 0.3s ease,left 0.3s ease,top 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.3s ease,height 0.3s ease,left 0.3s ease,top 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease,height 0.3s ease,left 0.3s ease,top 0.3s ease;
}

.image:hover
{
    width:150px;
    height:120px;
    left:-25px;
    top:-25px;
    z-index:9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think it's because the `click()` event will only work if the element exists when it is first called, but it's actually generated dynamically by the `replaceWith()`.

You can fix this by replacing click with `.live("click", function() {})`, for example:

```
jQuery("#myimg").live("click", function () {
    $(this).replaceWith( "<img id='myimgBig' src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0f510b2337a6077896036f31d4f45eb7?s=420' width='420' height='420' title='that&#39;s me' alt='Uddhab' />" );
});
jQuery("#myimgBig").live("click", function () {
    $(this).replaceWith( "<img id='myimg' src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0f510b2337a6077896036f31d4f45eb7?s=120' width='120' height='120' title='that&#39;s me' alt='Uddhab' />" );
});
```

Although really you should load both images at the same time and just use the click handler to hide and show them- it'll be a lot more responsive.

---

### Edit:

HTML:

```
<img src="image_small.jpg" class="images" id="#myimg" />
<img src="image_big.jpg" class="images" id="#myimgBig" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myimgBig").hide();
    $(".images").click(function() {
        $('.images').toggle();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q9gB8/

Comment: Take note .live() has been deprecated since v1.7, and is removed in 1.9 (replaced by .on()).

Answer (score 0):

just Try this also,

```
var zoomIn;
$("#myimg").click(function() {
var imgsrc = (zoomIn) ? "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0f510b2337a6077896036f31d4f45eb7?s=120" : "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0f510b2337a6077896036f31d4f45eb7?s=420";
$(this).attr('src', imgsrc); 
$(this).animate({
    width: (zoomIn) ? "120px" : "420px",
    height: (zoomIn) ? "120px" : "420px"
}, 1000);
zoomIn = !(zoomIn);
});
```

demo at : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6b84B/3/)